# Show that there exists a branch of logarithm $L$ so that $L(z+i)$ is defined on $\Omega $.

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Problem.

> Let $\Omega = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z: \text{Re}(z)=0\wedge \text{Im}(z)\leq -1\}$.
>
> Show that there exists a branch of logarithm $L$ so that $L(z+i)$ is defined on $\Omega $.

It might be a simple problem for most of you, but I would like to strengthen my knowledge of the branch of logarithms which I'm always confused with its concepts. So, any help would be really appreciated.

My Solution for this problem.

> Observe that for any $z\in \Omega$, we have that $z+i \in A:= \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z: \text{Re}(z)=0\wedge \text{Im}(z)\leq 0\}$.
>
> Let $L=\text{Log}_{-\frac{\pi }{2}}:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where we express $z=r\exp(i\theta ) $ $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ with $r=|z|$ and $\theta \in \left [ -\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{3\pi }{2} \right )$.
>
> Then for all $z \in \Omega$, we have that $L(z+i)=\log(r)+i\arg_{-\frac{\pi }{2}}(z+i)$ s.t $r=|z+i|$.
>
> This shows that $L(z+i)$ is defined on $\Omega$. $\blacksquare $

First of all, is my solution valid?

Moreover, I would like to know that if we can have a branch of logarithm whenever a domain doesn't include $0$.

Or is it definable only when a domain with no zero in it is simply connected?

Comment: You have the right idea; it's a straight-line branch cut from $0$ downward (toward the projective point $\infty$) along the negative imaginary axis. Your choice of $\theta$ looks fine. The answer to your question on non-simply-connected regions is "no" in the full generality you state it; for example, consider removing the origin from the unit disk. In short, the problem is that we must have a branch cut from $0$ to $\infty$ to make the logarithm single-valued, so we can not have the whole annulus (we have to remove some slit which the branch cut could pass through, e.g. the negative reals)